# Update SVN repository within web page

Tags: bash, cgi

I want to update server's SVN repository on server's URL request, so I user CGI shell script with Apache but it does not work as I needed. It's source:

```
#!/bin/sh    
cat << EOF
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<head>
<title>"SVN repository update.</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>"SVN repository updated:</h1>
EOF
echo `svn --help`
echo `svn`
echo `svn co`
echo `svn update /var/www/my_svn_repository`
echo `date`
cat << EOF
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

"echo `date`" and "echo `svn --help`" DO work - all other echos does not work (so svn repository is not updated). Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `svn` and `svn co` by themselves are not valid commands; they'll just print a help message and exit. I suspect the last one isn't, either; the path shouldn't point to the *repository*, but to the local working copy. Finally, it may matter who runs the script -- their ~/.svn directory will contain necessary information about the repository (the username and password to use for a remote repository, for example). You need to get a script that actually successfully does your update, first, and then try to turn it into a CGI script.

Comment: I do show these commands text output within HTML page and command `svn --help` does show svn's help message right within HTML page (the same text as shown within bash console) but other commands (like `svn` or `svn co`) do not show anything within HTML page (I thought it will show the same console's output too): `svn co` -> "svn: Try 'svn help' for more info \n svn: Not enough arguments provided" - but there are nothing.